# Magento is not adding the tax rate correctly

Tags: tax, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm trying to setup the tax rates for a client but for some reason the calculation is wrong.

New Zealand's tax rate is 15%. I only want to tax the sub total and show that. Shouldn't it be 23*0.15 = $3.45?

Current settings in Configuration -> Tax

**Tax Class**

- Tax Class for Shipping - Taxable Goods

**Calculation Settings**

- Tax Calculation Method Based On - total
- Tax Calculation Based On - shipping Address
- Catalog Prices - Including Tax
- Shipping Prices - Including Tax
- Apply Customer Tax - Before Discount
- Apply Discount On Prices - Excluding tax
- Apply Tax On - Custom Price if Available

**Price Display Settings**

- Display Product Prices In Catalog - Including Tax
- Display Shipping Prices - Including Tax

**Shopping Cart Display Settings**

- Display Prices - Including Tax
- Display Subtotal - Including Tax
- Display Shipping Amount - Including Tax

**Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings**

- Display Prices - Including Tax
- Display Subtotal - Including Tax
- Display Shipping Amount - Including Tax

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have set all your prices to already include tax so that means that the value 23.00 NZD is a combination of 20 NZD for the product and 3 NDZ of tax. The same goes for the shipping costs so that is 3.48 NZD for the shipping plus 0.52 NZD for the tax.